# UITableView frame exceeds the bounds of view controller and creates problems

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints

I have a `UITableView` inside a `UIViewController` and it's set to be full screen like this:

[image]

The `UIViewController` is set like this if it matters.

[image]

Now in my `viewDidLoad` method of the view controller, I'm simply printing the size out like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(UIScreen.main.bounds)
    print(self.view.bounds)
    print(self.view.frame)
    print(self.tableView.frame)
}
```

And then I get:

> (0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 568.0)
>
> (0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 568.0)
>
> (0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 568.0)
>
> (0.0, 64.0, 375.0, 554.0)

I know that 320 * 568 is correct for the simulator I used (iphone 5). From here it seems like the table view is actually outside of the screen. However it's showing up on the screen correctly, with padding 0 to all four sides.

Then the problem is that I have a text view in a cell and I need to calculate height of it base on its width, which comes from the cell width. The cell width is 375 in this case and it just screwed up the calculation. I also tested this on a real device and get the same thing.

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is too soon to worry about frames. Move your print statements to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: you can also have a look at the frames in `viewDidAppear`. They should be correct in that method

Comment: @rmaddy That does work but here is one more question. I seems like `cellForRow` is called before `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and it screws up my calculation. Are you suggesting me to call `reloadData()` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` so that table size is finalized?

Comment: No, do not do that. Like `viewDidLoad`, `cellForRowAt` is far too soon to get a proper frame. Implement the `tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)` delegate method.

Comment: inside `cellForRowAt` you can set things that you don't care about the exact frame of (for e.g. setting the text of a label) and then inside the `willDisplay` like rmaddy pointed out you can get the correct frames there, but from my own experiences I believe you have to call `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` first before doing anything inside of `willDisplay`